# TextSearch not working in flutter bloc in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I'm fetching the api data by using the library `flutter_bloc` and i have implemented pagination successfully and it's working well. There is `textfield` widget but when i try to search text it's not working or doing nothing. I have also checked on debug and in api response it's working well if i type anything on `textfield`. The problem is on `blocbuilder`, so highly appreciated if you have any solution of this issue.

> SearchPage

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}
class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  late SearchBloc searchBloc;
  final keyRefresh = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  final List<SearchData> search = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  late final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchBloc = BlocProvider.of<SearchBloc>(context)
      ..add(LoadAllRestaurantEvent());
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            currentFocus.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: Behavior(),
          child: Container(
            color: TuxedoColor.bodyColor,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                    'Discover Restaurants',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  )),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      TextField(
                        controller: controller,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        onChanged: (search) {
                          searchBloc.add(LoadSearchRestaurantEvent(search));
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          fillColor: TuxedoColor.whiteColor,
                          hintText: 'Search...',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            color: TuxedoColor.blackColor,
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              width: 0,
                              style: BorderStyle.none,),),
                          filled: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16),),),
                      Positioned(
                          right: 0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute<bool>(
                                    fullscreenDialog: true,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                        GoogleMapPage(),),);},
                              child: ImageIcon(
                                AssetImage('images/map.png'),
                                size: 25.0,),),)),],),),
                Container(
                  child: BlocBuilder<SearchBloc, SearchState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is LoadingAllRestaurantState) {
                      return Center();
                    } else if (state is LoadedAllRestaurantState) {
                      return buildNumberRestaurant(state.data);
                    } else if (state is ErrorAllRestaurantState) {
                      return Center(child: Text(state.message));
                    }
                    return Container();}),),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: BlocBuilder<SearchBloc, SearchState>(
                        builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is AllRestaurantStateInitial ||
                          state is LoadingAllRestaurantState &&
                              search.isEmpty) {
                        return Center(
                            child: PlatformCircularProgressIndicator());
                      } else if (state is LoadedAllRestaurantState) {
                        search.addAll(state.data);
                        BlocProvider.of<SearchBloc>(context).isFetching = false;
                        isLoading = false;
                      } else if (state is ErrorAllRestaurantState) {
                        return Center(child: Text(state.message));
                      }
                      return ListView.builder(
                        controller: scrollController
                          ..addListener(() {
                            if (scrollController.position.atEdge &&
                                !BlocProvider.of<SearchBloc>(context)
                                    .isFetching) {
                              if (scrollController.position.pixels != 0) {
                                BlocProvider.of<SearchBloc>(context)
                                  ..isFetching = true
                                  ..add(LoadAllRestaurantEvent());
                                isLoading = true;
                              }}}),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        primary: false,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: search.length + (isLoading ? 1 : 0),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (index < search.length) {
                            return buildAllSearchRestaurant(search[index]);
                          } else {
                            Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 30), () {
                              scrollController.jumpTo(
                                  scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);});
                            return Center(
                                child: PlatformCircularProgressIndicator());
                          }},);}),),),],),),),),);}
Widget buildAllSearchRestaurant(SearchData search) {
return Container(
child:Text(search.branchesLocales![0]!.name!,),)}
}
```

> SearchState

```
abstract class SearchState {}

class AllRestaurantStateInitial extends SearchState {}

class LoadingAllRestaurantState extends SearchState {}

class LoadedAllRestaurantState extends SearchState {
  final List<SearchData> data;

  LoadedAllRestaurantState(this.data);
}

class ErrorAllRestaurantState extends SearchState {
  final String message;

  ErrorAllRestaurantState(this.message);
}
```

> SearchEvent

```
abstract class SearchEvent {}

class LoadAllRestaurantEvent extends SearchEvent {}

class RefreshAllRestaurantEvent extends SearchEvent {}

class LoadSearchRestaurantEvent extends SearchEvent {
  final String search;

  LoadSearchRestaurantEvent(this.search);
}
```

> SearchBloc

```
class SearchBloc extends Bloc<SearchEvent, SearchState> {
  AllRestaurantDataService allRestaurantDataService;
  SearchRestaurantDataService searchRestaurantDataService;
  int page = 0;
  int searchPage = 0;
  bool isFetching = false;

  SearchBloc(this.allRestaurantDataService, this.searchRestaurantDataService)
      : super(AllRestaurantStateInitial());

  @override
  Stream<SearchState> mapEventToState(
    SearchEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoadAllRestaurantEvent || event is RefreshAllRestaurantEvent) {
      yield LoadingAllRestaurantState();
      try {
        List<SearchData> searchData = await allRestaurantDataService
            .makeRequestAllRestaurant(page) as List<SearchData>;
        yield LoadedAllRestaurantState(searchData);
        page++;
      } catch (e) {
        yield ErrorAllRestaurantState(e.toString());
      }
    } else if (event is LoadSearchRestaurantEvent) {
      yield LoadingAllRestaurantState();
      try {
        List<SearchData> searchData = await searchRestaurantDataService
                .makeRequestSearchRestaurant(event.search, searchPage)
            as List<SearchData>;
        yield LoadedAllRestaurantState(searchData);
        searchPage++;
      } catch (e) {
        yield ErrorAllRestaurantState(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```